# SQL Request results depending on data

Tags: sql, select

Maybe similar questions were there but i didn't find the right one.
So, here's the thing:

I have 3 tables.
First is EMPLOYEES with columns: e_id, name
Second is DEPARTMENTS with columns: p_id, name
Third is ASSIGNMENTS with columns: e_id, january, february, march
e_id - employee id
p_id - project id

In third column january, february, march columns contain project ids and they maybe different for each month.

So, I'm trying to get the following result:

Get employee id, employee name, department id in january, department name in january, department id in feb and etc.
the major problem is to get department name for each month. In tried ON but it gives only first match.

For example:

```
SELECT e.name, e.surname, ea.employee_id, ea.p_jan, d.name, ea.p_feb,d.name,ea.p_mar,ea.p_apr,ea.p_may FROM employee_assignments ea right join employee e ON e.id=ea.employee_id left join department d on d.id=ea.p_jan;
```

Or maybe there's better way to organise third table?
Thanks in advance

Comment: RIGHT JOIN, combined with LEFT JOIN...!?! Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.)

Comment: Well i can use this approach: 
SELECT e.name, e.surname, ea.employee_id, ea.p_jan, p.name, ea.p_feb,k.name,ea.p_mar,ea.p_apr,ea.p_may FROM employee_assignments ea right join employee e ON e.id=ea.employee_id left join projects p on p.id=ea.p_jan left join projects k on k.id=ea.p_feb 
--------------
so I will do left join for projects 12 times(for 12 months) and it works, but is there more elegant approach?

Comment: I don't get it. You have a column for every month? Shouldn't this be in rows instead? What happens next year?

Comment: yes, column for every month. The idea is that any employee may (or may not) get new project assignment every month, that's why i put month in the columns. If I use row - I should have table for each employee then, right?

Comment: What, no. You have a single table of `EmployeeAssignment` and it has three columns: employee, assignment and month. Both of those columns would be part of the primary key.